# How to retrieve the SoftLayer_Network_Gateway credentials using Softlayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to retrieve the Network Gateway (Vyatta routers) credentials for doing the configuration over REST.

I can see the list of Network Gateway associated with my account using below REST call:
curl -s https://username:apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways

Comment: What does this have to do with Go (as tagged) or programming in general?

Comment: I am developing my application using Go that's the reason , but you are correct this was not required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following REST call to get the passwords of all members into each gateway:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkGateways?objectMask=mask[id,name,networkSpace,status.name,members[priority,hardware[id,fullyQualifiedDomainName,operatingSystem[id,passwords[username,password]]]]]
```